# Spring, JIRA : Maven repository and dependency not working

Tags: maven, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I am working on a Spring project in which I would to integrate JIRA functionality so users can send bug reports from platform directly into JIRA and retrieve as well. Unfortunately when I put the repository URL and dependency, it says, not found and illegal content in repository code. What am I doing wrong?

I would appreciate any examples as well for achieving the task I mentioned above. Thanks a lot.

Here is my POM.xml

```
 <repository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-components</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

What shall I do. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose the definition of your repository inside the `<repositories>` tag, like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <!-- Your repository -->
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Cool, that worked, how could I have missed it, so stupid of me. While we are on JIRA, any good examples you got.... ones on net are very shallow at best.